# Creating .ICS files as attachments in Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, icalendar, email-attachments

I work for a College in the UK and for some time we have been automatically emailing our prospective students with their 'personalized' interview appointment date and time.  We would like to include an attachment to the email containing an .ics or .ical file, so the student can add the appointment to their calendar of choice very easily.

Most email packages (or mobile devices) recognize .ics files as calendar appointments and give you a 'one-click' option to add it to your calendar - this is exactly how we would want it to work - one click and it's there!

Despite the (.ics) file format being relatively easy to understand and generate, so far we have not been successful in creating it and adding it an attachment.

Has anyone been successful doing this and if so would you be willing to share how you did it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can upload .ics file on report server or on accessible location and then provide a hyperlink on report to download/open that file.

Comment: I perhaps should have said, each appointment is personalized, so I can't get away with a single 'linked' file.  an ICS file is a simple text file but with very specific json-like tags, and generating the necessary file format is quite easy, its getting SSRS to include it as an attachment is where we are having problems..

Comment: Were you able to solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently developed an open-source solution in CLR for sending calendar invitations (ical / ics) from within SQL Server.

This works:

https://github.com/EitanBlumin/sql_clr_ics